# How to call refreshData() on main page from components/functions.tsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do a props refresh with this in default function Home()

```
const router = useRouter()
const refreshData = () => router.replace(router.asPath);
```

I want to refreshData() after an apicall
Button is created with

```
import * as functions from "../components/funkcje";
```

`{functions.button(id)}`

**/compontents/funckje.tsx**

```
export function button(id:number){
      return(
            <button onClick={() => zmien_stan(0, id)}>
                  Zmien Stan
            </button>
      )
}
```

**How can i call refreshData() on main page after got response**

```
async function zmien_stan(typ:number, id:number){
      const response = await fetch('/api/db', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: id, type: typ})
          });
        
          if (!response.ok){
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
          }
          return await response.json();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing

```
const router = useRouter();
```

You can only access `router` within hooks. Therefore, what you need to do is to declare a hook that exposes `refreshData`:

```
// useRefreshData.ts

const useRefreshData = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const refreshData = () => router.replace(router.asPath);

  return refreshData;
}
```

And then use it

```
// Button.tsx
export function Button(id:number){
      const refreshData = useRefreshData();

      return(
            <button onClick={() => zmien_stan(0, id).then(() => refreshData())}>
                  Zmien Stan
            </button>
      )
}
```